# How to prevent resolving particular paths as modules in Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am updating `@vue/cli-service` from `4.5.15` to `5.0.6` in my project and it leads to errors when bundling:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/assets/img/my-image.png' in 'C:\some-path-here\folder-name'`

The image is defined in `MyComponent.vue` as follows:

```
<style>
.my-component {
  background: url(/assets/img/my-image.png);
}
</style>
```

These are also some of my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.6",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0"
  }
```

This is my understanding of what happens:

- Webpack 5 is configured in Vue CLI 5.0.6 to find `my-image.png` somewhere in my project. This file doesn't exist in my project and Webpack will never find it.
- Webpack 4 is not configured in Vue CLI 4.5.15 to find any assets in my project and it keeps paths as is.

Basically, I don't want Webpack to search for any assets (i.e. images and fonts) in my project, I want it to keep paths as is. A browser will find my assets based on the paths I defined myself.

Is there a way to prevent resolving particular paths in Webpack / Vue CLI? For example, if they start with "/assets" or end with particular file extensions?

I tried something like this but it does not help:

```
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
                resourceRegExp: /^\.(png|woff)$/
            })
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I got issues regarding the updates in vue cli and webpack, I get:
ERROR ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options